# How to create an Excel UserForm and controls from Java?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, vba

I have used "Apache POI" in order to create an Excel spreadsheet from Java.

As a next step I would like to create also `UserForms` from Java with Excel `UserForm` Controls, like labels, buttons, `textBoxes`  and so on. I used to program such `UserForms` with `VBA` Excel.

As far as I know, Apache POI does not offer such ability (correct me if I am wrong).

Do you know an other way, in order to create `UserForms` with controls from Java?
Is there an other framework like "Apache POI" which gives such ability to Java developers?

In case you are aware of such framework, please let me know.

Comment: I believe nobody will recreate the whole `Excel` functionality, inclusive `VBA` macros, where `UserForms` are part of, in `Java` in short future. So you could have a `*.xlsm` template with that UserForm and the related macros and then fill only the Worksheets with `apache poi`.

Comment: @Axel: Thank you for your answer. I was thinking the exact same thing that you suggested, but I was hopping that there is still something out there that could fit my expectations.

Answer (score 0):

There no such forms in Java as far as am aware, but you can generate a forms and other GUI controls with java Swing/awt framework.

Here sample demo http://www.edu4java.com/en/swing/swing3.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, with SWING you can create an external form, but what I need, is to create an internal UserForm in Excel file (VBA UserForm), so that when the user opens the .xlsx file, to be able to use this UserForm locally from his Excel file. I create dynamically an Excel file through Java by using "Apache POI". In the same way I want to find a way to program a UserForm from Java, which will be included in the extracted Excel file. I do not know yet, whether it is feasible or not.

Comment: Creating and pushing macrose into excel document is Apache POI's one of limitation https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/limitations.html

Comment: Yes you are right, therefore I am asking whether there is an other framework that I can use instead of "Apache POI". If you know any, do not hesitate sending it.